# Any automate way to copy data from Amazon EFS to S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-efs

I am looking for an efficient way to periodically copy data from EFS to S3. I know I am able to create a cron job and use S3 cli to move the data, but I was wondering if there is any existing service or ETL data pipeline on AWS that is able to copy data from EFS to S3 periodically.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you were looking for [DataSync](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datasync/latest/userguide/create-s3-location.html)? Not sure if it can be configured to run periodically, but there are reusable/re-invocable "tasks" to redo a preconfigured copy "path"

Answer (score 0):

You are right; you can create a cron job and use AWS CLI. There is no existing service to do this.

Answer (score 0):

s3 sync : Syncs directories and S3 prefixes. Recursively copies new and updated files from the source directory to the destination. Only creates folders in the destination if they contain one or more files.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html